# Greedy algorithms in two pointer techniques(fast and slow runnner)

Tags: java, algorithm

I am learning the Two-Pointer Technique in [Two-pointer Technique - Scenario II](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/array-and-string/205/array-two-pointer-technique/1157/)

It introduced fast-runner pointer and slow-runner pointer to move elements and return the new length

```py
public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
        if (nums[i] != val) {
            nums[k] = nums[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

A summary follows:

This is a very common scenario of using the two-pointer technique when you need:

> One slow-runner and one fast-runner at the same time.

The key to solving this kind of problems is to

> Determine the movement strategy for both pointers.

Similar to the previous scenario, you might sometimes need to `sort` the array before using the two-pointer technique. And you might need a `greedy` thought to determine your movement strategy.

Reference to

> And you might need a `greedy` thought to determine your movement strategy.

The `greedy`here is confusing since we take `greedy` as the fundamental greedy algorithms for granted.

What kinds of greedy algorithms thought can be employed in two pointer?

Could you please help an example?

[image]

Comment: You're linking to a password protected site. Please only reference publicly accessible content.

Comment: *"Could you please help an example?"* There are 3 tests to "Scenario II", and tests 2 ([Max Consecutive Ones](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/array-and-string/205/array-two-pointer-technique/1301/)) and 3 ([Minimum Size Subarray Sum](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/array-and-string/205/array-two-pointer-technique/1299/)) are both examples for greedy algorithm. They hints at "greedy" on the page you show, because you need it for the tests.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> What kinds of greedy algorithms thought can be employed in two
>   pointer?

Consider this problem [3sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/) in LeetCode.

This problem requires sorting the input array prior to applying two-pointers method. When you're sorting the input array in some order, this is pretty greedy way to attack a problem.

Consider another problem [Container With Most Water](https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/) in LeetCode.

I don't want to give you spoiler solution for this problem incase you didn't solve it yet. But to give you some idea how it relates to greedy approach, you need to advance left and right pointer based on some comparison between numbers which is actually kind of "Greedy".